# How do I convert from JSON/object to dotenv?

Tags: node.js, json, dotenv

I have some secrets stored in AWS as JSON. For example:

```json
{
    DB_HOST: "foo.com",
    DB_USER: "admin",
    DB_PASS: "my$ecur3P4ssw0rd"
}
```

I've written a tool which pulls those secrets down from AWS, and I want to be able to convert to dotenv and write a .env file.

```
DB_HOST="foo.com"
DB_USER="admin"
DB_PASS="my$ecur3P4ssw0rd"
```

The Node.js dotenv package has documentation showing [dotenv string => object conversion](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#parsing), but I'm surprised it has no mention of converting object => dotenv string. I'm sure I could write that convertor myself, but this seems like such a basic use case that I feel like I must be missing something. How am I supposed to do this conversion?

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const config = {
    DB_HOST: "foo.com",
    DB_USER: "admin",
    DB_PASS: "my$ecur3P4ssw0rd"
};

const env = Object.entries(config).map(
  ([key, value]) => `${key}: "${value}"`
).join('\n');

fs.writeFileSync('.env', env);
```

Comment: This is probably good enough, but it doesn't handle cases like nested objects or escaping double quotes. I _could_ code that out, but now that's starting to feel like its own project to maintain, and I was hoping there was just some vetted, built-in way to handle this.

Comment: There is [`envfile.stringify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envfile), but doesn't handle nested objects (and I think it is fine!).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where exactly you get the variables from, given that probably the AWS APIs give them to you as JSON, in my experience:

1. You could use this [jq](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/jq.1.html) command:

```
echo $SERVICE_SECRET | jq -r "to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\\\"\(.value|tostring)\\\"\")|.[]" >> /var/www/.env
```

... after we've got the variables from AWS secrets manager injected in `AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition` CloudFormation as:

```
Secrets:
 - Name: SERVICE_SECRET
   ValueFrom: arn::...
```

2. Or... another approach would be to fetch them from AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store and parse them like this:

```
VARIABLE_PATH="/your-service/config/path/"
SECRET_STRING=$(aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --recursive --with-decryption --path=${VARIABLE_PATH}  |jq -cr ".Parameters|map(.Name |= ltrimstr(\"${VARIABLE_PATH}\"))|from_entries")
```

then put them in AWS Secrets Manager like this:

```
aws secretsmanager update-secret --secret-id "[your-secret-name]" --secret-string "${SECRET_STRING}"
```

then use Approach 1 to inject them in your app.